# How do I make windows appear in the tab well next to a previously opened tab in Visual Studio when I open them?

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-2017

When I open a window in Visual Studio 2017, either when debugging or when I use Intellisense to view a class method definition, I find that the window is not opened in the tab well (e.g. in the screenshot, I want the green tab to be next to the yellow tab when it is opened, not far apart as it appears).

[image: Far apart tabs]

I am guessing that the settings to change will be in 'Tools' > 'Options' > 'Environment' > 'Tabs and Windows', but I am not sure which checkboxes to check to ensure that I get the behaviour I want.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the **Preview Tab** group of options:

[image]

You can uncheck **Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab**.

Comment: Thanks, Sergey - that was indeed it.